# Linux System Calls problems using Fork() passing ints to child and parent processes

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am working on a program that will take an integer and create two processes, a parent and a child. The parent will subtract 5 from the integer, pass it to the child who will divide it by 5, and then they will repeat this process 5 times, each time printing the current value of the integer.

The integer can be passed through a text file and be both written and read off of, or a pipeline can be used which ever is simpler.

I have been looking up the systems calls needed, and have a semi working program. I have been stuck for hours however, and I think my issue is that I can't get them to wait for each other to finish because my output is incorrect.

Here is what I got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{    
    int x=19530;
    int w=1;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();

    int k;
    for (k=0; k<5; k++) {
        if (pid>0) {
            //int x = 19530;

            if ((close(fd[0]))==-1) {
                perror("Close:");
            }

            read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int));
            x=x-5;
            write (fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
            printf("X in parent %d\n", x);

            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);
        } else if (pid==0) {

            if ((close(fd[1]))==-1) {
                perror("Close:");
            }

            read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int));
            x=x/5;
            printf("X in child %d\n", x);
            write (fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));

            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However my output is an issue, I am getting:

```
X in parent 19525
X in child 3905
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in parent 19520
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in parent 19515
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in parent 19510
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in parent 19505
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in child 781
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in child 156
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in child 31
Close:: Bad file descriptor
X in child 6
```

It seems to start off well, but then the child doesn't pass back properly then the parent runs too many times in a row before the child catches up. I also been trying to fix that bad file descriptor but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can neither read from nor write to a file descriptor after you close it.

Comment: You create a pair of file descriptors. Then, you close them 5 times. And after the first time you close it, it's closed. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: You have each side doing a `read` first followed by a `write`.  A `read` will block until someone calls `write`, so who writes first?

Comment: @immibis, the `fork()` is outside the loop.  The child will not fork when it cycles the loop.

Comment: Additionally to the issue with prematurely closing the pipe ends, you indeed do have a problem with making the processes wait for each other.  Pipes can help with that, as reading from a pipe blocks on data being available, but that doesn't work for you because each process can read back from the pipe whatever it just wrote.  One would normally establish *two* pipes, each one used unidirectionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

#define ok(x) ({ int i_ = (x); if (i_ == -1) err(1, #x); i_; })

enum { p_, c_ }; // parent, child
enum { r_, w_ }; // read, write

int main(void)
{
        int x = 19530;
        int fd[2][2];
        int pid;

        ok(pipe(fd[0]));
        ok(pipe(fd[1]));

        ok(pid = fork());

        close(fd[p_][pid ? r_ : w_]);
        close(fd[c_][pid ? w_ : r_]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (pid) {
                        x -= 5;
                        printf("X in parent %d\n", x);
                        ok(write(fd[p_][w_], &x, sizeof(x)));
                        ok(read(fd[c_][r_], &x, sizeof(x)));
                }
                else {
                        ok(read(fd[p_][r_], &x, sizeof(x)));
                        x /= 5;
                        printf("X in child %d\n", x);
                        ok(write(fd[c_][w_], &x, sizeof(x)));
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Pipes are unidirectional, so you need two.  I used some enums to try and make things easier to read.

Comment: You're using a GCC extension (['statement expressions'](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)) without calling that out.  Using `<err.h>` is interesting; it is available on BSD (including Mac OS X) and Linux, but not necessarily anywhere else.  OTOH, it is very much along the lines of a set of error reporting routines I've been using for the last 25 years or so.  Personally, I find the single-letter, trailing underscore names distracting.

Comment: There's an open source implementation of err.h at CCAN should anyone need it: http://ccodearchive.net/info/err.html.  Statement expressions are supported by gcc, clang, and even icc - so I feel pretty good about it. :)