# Kill process if file descriptor on other end closed

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I am making a program that creates n number of deamons that will communicate with primary process. Deamons send invidual msg through fifo, when they get sigusr1 signal. When primary process gets sigusr1, it closes random fifo. When random fifo is closed I want the deamon that communicates through that fifo to die. It seems to not work... Although file descriptor is closed the deamon is still alive and still doesn't die when sigusr1 is send. (every deamons must be in the same group).

Is it possible to connect 2 ends of fifos to 2 processes and synchronise it?

Comment: Usually, the line after `execl` is more like `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` since you only get there if `execl` fails.

Comment: does it affect my problem? Because everything else seems to work

Comment: No, it is not likely to be relevant, but it is odd.

Comment: Your code does not appear to be complete. For example, where is the code that does this: "When primary process gets sigusr1, it closes random fifo"? And how about the code that is supposed to kill or exit the daemon. Doesn't seem to be any code to do that either. So its really not clear how you intend the current code is supposed to be working.

Comment: ok I will complete my code in sec w8

Comment: ok I have edited code

Answer (score 2):

Closing one end of a fifo does not signal the other end.  A write to the other end will block until there is a reader.  I think the semantics of a socket would be a better match here.  Another option is to use a pair of fifos, one for each direction.  The second fifo provides an ACK, or an explicit QUIT message.

Comment: isn't there a way to duplicate file descriptor?

Comment: yes, but `dup(2)` doesn't give you another fifo.  To get another, call `mkfifo(3)` again.  If you'd rather use pipes, here's some [example code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302981/linux-system-calls-problems-using-fork-passing-ints-to-child-and-parent-proces/35307887#35307887)  for two way pipes from an answer I posted yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but in the daemon’s code you shouldn’t put an exit function in order to exit the daemon child process and the father can take the exit status?

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.